# Como saber cual es el elemento que le sigue a otro en un arreglo

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo que me devuelve cual es el primer y último elemento de un arreglo usando `foreach`

```
 $array  = array("dog", "rabbit", "horse", "rat", "cat");
    foreach($array as $index => $animal) {
        if ($index === array_key_first($array))
            echo $animal; // output: dog
    
        if ($index === array_key_last($array))
            echo $animal; // output: cat
    }
```

Pero me gustaría obtener el primer elemento de un arreglo dada una condición, ejemplo tengo este arreglo

```
$array  = array("---", "---", "horse", "rat", "cat");
```

Como pudiera obtener el elemento que le sigue al último elemento `"---"` usando el `foreach` o si existe alguna función propia de php que permita esto.

Comment: Intenta con [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0):

Usa `array_reduce` para acarrear ya sea el último `---` o el primer elemento posterior.

```
$x = array_reduce( ['---', '---', 'horse', 'rat', 'cat']
                 , function($c, $e){ 
                     if( $e === '---' )
                        return '---';
                     if( $c === '---' )
                        return $e;
                     return $c;
                   } 
                 );
echo $x; // horse
```

Que en una línea críptica puede reducirse a:

```
$x = array_reduce( ['---',  'horse', 'rat', 'cat']
                 , function($c,$e){ return $e==='---'?'---':$c==='---'?$e:$c; } 
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

array_search busca la primera coincidencia, si necesitamos la última invertimos la matriz, y luego restamos 1 al índice.
ˋˋˋ
$array  = array("---", "---", "horse", "rat", "cat");
$indice=array_search(2,array_reverse($array))-1;
if($indice>0)
print(array_reverse($array)[$indice]);
else
print("No existe coincidencia";

ˋˋˋ

Answer (score 0):

Esta función recibe 3 argumentos: El array, el elemento a buscar, y un opcional si considera valores repetidos o no.

Si `$uniq` es `true`, se eliminan todos los valores repetidos con `array_unique()`.

Se recorre cada elemento del array con un `foreach`. Si el elemento actual == al elemento a buscar (`elseif`), se cambia la bandera `found` a `true`. En la siguiente iteración (y próximo elemento), va a entrar en el `if($found)` retornando ese elemento a la llamada de la función.

```
<?php
function siguiente_elemento($array, $elem, $uniq=false) {
    if($uniq) {
        $array = array_unique($array);
    }
    $found = false;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if($found) {
            return $value;
        } elseif($value == $elem) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Pruebas

```
$array = array("---", "---", "horse", "rat", "cat");
var_dump(siguiente_elemento($array, '---')); // "---"
var_dump(siguiente_elemento($array, '---', true)); // "horse"
var_dump(siguiente_elemento($array, 'cat')); // false
var_dump(siguiente_elemento($array, 'seal')); // false

// Con un array asociativo
$array = array('a'=>"---", 'c'=>"horse", 'q'=>"rat", 'x'=>"cat");
var_dump(siguiente_elemento($array, 'horse')); // "rat"
```